# Full-screen background images in website looks blurry

Tags: jquery, css, image, web, background

visit my site here: http://www.oneniceday.com

The background image looks really blurry on my screen even though the image size is 1920 x 1080 px. I'm using a jquery script to handle this bg thing as the css method all gave me undesired results one way or another.

Is there any way to fix this blurring problem?

Comment: It seems your uploaded image size is 960x540 not 1920 x 1080

Answer (score 2):

```
.backgroundImage
{
position: fixed;

background-image: url(bg2.jpg);
background-size: cover;
-webkit-filter: blur(12px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
 filter: blur(5px);
z-index: 0;
}
```

Its work for me try

Answer (score 0):

This problem is something I come across often too.

The image is not HD, (it has a low pixel rate) so your eyes have a tendency to see each pixel separately, giving you the blurry effect. It's not your code. If you took the image yourself, try taking it with a different device. If you looked it up online, try putting the keyword "HD" in your search.

If the picture has more pixels when you just open the picture file by itself and enlarge it to full screen, than you can upload it into your code as a file with more pixels

Comment: Other than the advice to try to find a higher res version of the image, this answer doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

tks for the reply! I found out the issue: it's because of this Adaptive Images script and the .htaccess file which is auto-resizing all my images! It works fine now! Tks! :-)